# Galois group Abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

$\omega$ is the primitive $4^{th}$ root of unity, then find $Gal\left(\mathbb{Q\left(\sqrt{2},\omega\right)/\mathbb{Q}}\right).$

First i calculate order of $Gal\left(\mathbb{Q\left(\sqrt{2},\omega\right)/\mathbb{Q}}\right)$ which is $4$ by use of minimal polynomial.

$\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},\omega\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]=\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},\omega\right):\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega\right)\right]\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]$

$\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},\omega\right):\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega\right)\right]=2$

$\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]=2$ because $x^2+1$ is minimal polynomial.

Therefore $\left[\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},\omega\right):\mathbb{Q}\right]=2\times 2=4$.

(I am not sure that i calculate right)

I don't know how elements of $Gal\left(\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2},\omega\right)/\mathbb{Q}\right)$ look like.

I think it is of the type

$\varepsilon=\omega \rightarrow \omega,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow \sqrt{2}$

$\alpha=\omega\rightarrow \omega^2,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow \sqrt{2}$

$\beta=\omega\rightarrow \omega^3,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow \sqrt{2}$

$\gamma=\omega \rightarrow \omega,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow \omega\sqrt{2}$.

Four elements complete here and i think i did wrong.

Any hint how to find element.

Thank you.

Comment: Neither $\alpha$ nor $\gamma$ yields a valid map.  Note the image of $\omega$ must still satisfy $x^2+1=0$.  Similarly the image of $\sqrt{2}$ must still satisfy $x^2-2=0$

Comment: The primitive $4$th root of unity is often known as $i$.  An automorphism has to send $i$ to a **primitive** $4$th root of unity so there are only two choices:  $\pm i$.

Comment: so the four elements are first $i\rightarrow i,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow \sqrt{2}$ second $i\rightarrow -i,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow\sqrt{2}$ third $i\rightarrow i,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow i\sqrt{2}$ and fourth $i\rightarrow i,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow -i\sqrt{2}$ !!

Comment: A few points: to the level that you're pitching your proof, you should include *why* $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt{2}) :\mathbb{Q}(\omega) ] = 2$. For the main question it would be helpful for you to compute the galois groups of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega) / \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) / \mathbb{Q}$ first - then see if you can patch them together.

Comment: @user462999 if $\sigma : \sqrt{2} \mapsto i \sqrt{2}$ you'll end up with $\sqrt{2}^2 - 2 = 0 \neq -4 = (i \sqrt{2})^2 - 2$ so the image does not satisfy the min poly...

Comment: ohh! so $\sqrt{2}\rightarrow\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}\rightarrow -\sqrt{2}$ with $i\rightarrow -i$ and $i\rightarrow -i$

Comment: @user462999 ummm possibly, what you're saying is a little unclear. The "building blocks" are $i \mapsto -i$ and $\sqrt{2} \mapsto -\sqrt{2}$ - what combinations of these can you create?

Comment: $i\rightarrow i,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow \sqrt{2}$ and $i\rightarrow -i,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow \sqrt{2}$ and  $i\rightarrow i,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow -\sqrt{2}$ and $i\rightarrow -i,~\sqrt{2}\rightarrow -\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \omega)$ is the compositum of two Galois fields extensions, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $Q(\omega)$ and hence also Galois over $\mathbb Q$.

Note that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2) \cap \mathbb Q(\omega) =\mathbb Q$.

This induces a group homomorphism.

$$\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \omega)/ \mathbb Q)\rightarrow \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)/\mathbb Q) \times \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\omega )/\mathbb Q)\cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 $$
$$\sigma\mapsto (\sigma|_{\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)}, \sigma|_{\mathbb Q(\omega)} ) $$

This is injective and hence by cardinality arguments, an isomorphism. So we get $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2, \omega)/ \mathbb  Q) \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 $

Comment: Not such a fan of this answer, while correct, since the attack of OP is one which works - they've just written down the wrong automorphisms...